# Proof of inequality for singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

I have two questions:

I wonder how to prove inequalities involving the singular values of matrix A*B such as
 [image]

Using the definition meaning that largest singular value is max ||AX|| over all ||X||=1 and minimum singular value is min ||AX|| over all ||X||=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matrices $A$, $B$, the singular values of $AB$ are the eigenvalues of
$$
       \sqrt{(AB)^{\star}(AB)} = \sqrt{B^{\star}A^{\star}AB}
$$
Using inner product notation: $\lambda_{A}$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $\sqrt{A^{\star}A}$ and $\Lambda_{A}$ its largest *iff* the following holds for all vectors $x$:
$$
              \lambda_{A}^{2}(x,x) \le (A^{\star}Ax,x) \le \Lambda_{A}^{2}(x,x).
$$
Building on this, let $x=By$:
$$
              \lambda_{A}^{2}(By,By) \le (A^{\star}ABy,By) \le \Lambda_{A}^{2}(By,By),\\
              \lambda_{A}^{2}(B^{\star}By,y) \le ((AB)^{\star}(AB)y,y) \le \Lambda_{A}^{2}(B^{\star}By,y)  \;\;\; (\dagger)
$$
The first inequality of $(\dagger)$ gives the following for all vectors $y$:
$$
                \lambda_{A}^{2}(B^{\star}By,y) \le  \Lambda_{AB}^{2}(y,y) \\
                   \implies \lambda_{A}^{2}\Lambda_{B}^{2} \le \Lambda_{AB}^{2}
$$
That's what you want. Similarly, the second of $(\dagger)$ gives $\Lambda_{AB}^{2} \le \Lambda_{A}^{2}\Lambda_{B}^{2}$.

Comment: is there any way to prove it using definition that largest singular value is max ||AX|| over all ||X||=1 and minimum singular value is min ||AX|| over all ||X||=1. I will edit my question as well.

Comment: I believe ((AB)*(AB)y,y) gives you norm of ABy but this is not equal to largest singular value of AB. can you explain how you got it equal to max singular value of AB?

Comment: @user1 : The definition I am using is equivalent, but more convenient. If $(A^{\star}Ax,x) \le \Lambda^{2}(x,x)$ for all $x$, then $\|A^{\star}x\|/\|x\|\le |\Lambda|$ for $x \ne 0$ and vice versa. Give it a little thought and you'll see the equivalence. And it works for any matrix, including $AB$. Same with $\lambda^{2}(x,x) \le (A^{\star}Ax,x)$.

Comment: @user1 : The other identity that you might not have realized is that, for any matrix $M$ and vector $x$, $\|Mx\|^{2}=(Mx,Mx)=(M^{\star}Mx,x)$.

Comment: Thanks. However my question is about your last two lines: because you correctly mention above that (B*By,y)<largest eigenvalue of (By) but in the line before last line you are replacing the (B*By,y) by its upper bound and I do not think it gives you right inequality.

Comment: @user1 : Once you have $\lambda_{A}^{2}(x,x) \le (A^{\star}Ax,x)$ for all $x$, for example, then you can set $x=By$. Then $\lambda_{A}^{2}(By,By) \le (A^{\star}ABy,By)$ for all $y$. When you move things across inner-products, they go on the left with a $\star$. So $(A^{\star}ABy,By)=(B^{\star}A^{\star}ABy,y)$. $\star$ reverses order. So $B^{\star}A^{\star}=(AB)^{\star}$. So $B^{\star}A^{\star}AB=(AB)^{\star}(AB)$. Now you're dealing with $C^{\star}C$ again, where $C=AB$. Does that help?

Comment: I understand that part what I do not understand is you can replace that (B*By,y) by something smaller and still satisfies the inequality but you cannot replace it by something bigger. Can you elaborate about this? How did you get the last line from the line before it ?

Comment: I start with $\lambda_A^{2}(B^{\star}By,y) \le ((AB)^{\star}(AB)y,y)$; by definition of $\Lambda_{AB}$, you also have $((AB)^{\star}(AB)y,y) \le \Lambda_{AB}^{2}(y,y)$. Therefore $\lambda_A^{2}(B^{\star}By,y) \le \Lambda_{AB}^{2}(y,y)$ must hold because $a \le b \le c \implies a \le c$. But $(B^{\star}By,y) \le \alpha^{2}(y,y)$ for all $y$ iff $\Lambda_{B}^{2} \le \alpha^{2}$. By definition, the best upper bound involves $\Lambda_{B}$. $\alpha$ may not be as tight.

Comment: I agree about this too. Then how did you change the lambda(B*By,y) to lambda(A)^2* (largest eigenvalue)(B)^2 . Sorry I do not know how I type the same way you type.

Comment: So you agree that it has been show that $\lambda_{A}^{2}(B^{\star}By,y) \le \Lambda_{AB}^{2}(y,y)$ for all $y$. Assume $\lambda_{A}\ne 0$. Then $(B^{\star}By,y) \le\frac{\Lambda_{AB}^{2}}{\lambda_{A}^{2}}(y,y)$. The right side is not necessary the best bound. So $\Lambda_{B}^{2} \le\frac{\Lambda_{AB}^{2}}{\lambda_{A}^{2}}$ which gives $\Lambda_{B}^{2}\lambda_{A}^{2} \le \Lambda_{AB}^{2}$. If $\lambda_{A}=0$, then the inequality trivially holds anyway.

Comment: I believe the fact that inequality is correct for all y so we can pick the y that makes (B*By,y) maximum so we replace its value by largest possible and that lets prove the inequality.

Comment: It's a useful criterion that $(B^{\star}By,y) \le C^{2}(y,y)$ for all $y$ iff $\Lambda_{B} \le C^{2}$. And $c^{2}(y,y) \le (B^{\star}By,y)$ for all $y$ iff $c^{2} \le \lambda_{B}^{2}$. This criteria as stated holds in infinite-dimensional spaces, too, where the min/max may not be achieved, but the best bounds still exist. :)